# Dropdown not updating based on scope value angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been working on some functionality over last few days.

Whenever I select a dropdown, index values needs to be captured. At the same time, when I click remove button, one TV should be removed and the remaining TV's should be updated in the dropdown.

But the issue is when removing selected tv, index value is updated but ng model (dropdown) is not updated with `connectTVs.index` value. Where I'm missing?

Here is the code snippet.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.noOfTVs = [{
    index: 0,
    value: 'How many Dish TVs?'
  }, {
    index: 1,
    value: 'Connect 1 Dish TV'
  }, {
    index: 2,
    value: 'Connect 2 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 3,
    value: 'Connect 3 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 4,
    value: 'Connect 4 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 5,
    value: 'Connect 5 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 6,
    value: 'Connect 6 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 7,
    value: 'Connect 7 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 8,
    value: 'Connect 8 Dish TVs'
  }];
  $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[0];
  $scope.onChangeMethod = function(connectTVsIndex) {
    // Doing some actions
    $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[connectTVsIndex];
    alert($scope.connectTVs.index);
  }
  $scope.removetv = function(connectTVsIndex) {
    $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[connectTVsIndex];
    $scope.connectTVs.index = $scope.connectTVs.index - 1;
    alert($scope.connectTVs.index);

  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
<h3>Demo App</h3>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="connectTV" aria-label="How many Dish TVs"
            ng-model="connectTVs"
            ng-change="onChangeMethod(connectTVs.index)"
            class="selector" aria-required="true"
            ng-options="noOfTV as noOfTV.value for noOfTV in noOfTVs">
  </select>

<br><br>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="removetv(connectTVs.index)">Remove TV </button>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't get what you want to achieve here. You want to remove the selected tv and update the value of `$scope.connectTVs` to what ?

Comment: yes when removing selected tv, ng model needs to be selected with $scope.connectTVs.index value

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.noOfTVs = [{
    index: 0,
    value: 'How many Dish TVs?'
  }, {
    index: 1,
    value: 'Connect 1 Dish TV'
  }, {
    index: 2,
    value: 'Connect 2 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 3,
    value: 'Connect 3 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 4,
    value: 'Connect 4 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 5,
    value: 'Connect 5 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 6,
    value: 'Connect 6 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 7,
    value: 'Connect 7 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 8,
    value: 'Connect 8 Dish TVs'
  }];
  $scope.connectTVs = {}
  $scope.connectTVs['val'] = $scope.noOfTVs[0];
  $scope.onChangeMethod = function(connectTVsIndex) {
    // Doing some actions
    $scope.connectTVs['val'] = $scope.noOfTVs[connectTVsIndex];
    alert($scope.connectTVs['val'].index);
  }
  $scope.removetv = function(connectTVsIndex) {
    alert($scope.connectTVs['val'].index);
    console.log(connectTVsIndex)
    $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[connectTVsIndex];
    $scope.connectTVs.index = $scope.connectTVs.index - 1;

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="connectTV" aria-label="How many Dish TVs" ng-model="connectTVs['val']" ng-change="onChangeMethod(connectTVs['val'].index)" class="selector" aria-required="true" ng-options="noOfTV as noOfTV.value for noOfTV in noOfTVs">
      </select>
    <br><br>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="removetv(connectTVs['val'].index)">Remove TV </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where you are getting this Error?After removing what you need do?

Comment: just click "remove tv" twice to replicate the error

Comment: After  RemoveTv which one u want to selected  index? After RemoveTv do u want to keep the value in  $scope.noOfTVs?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't need to change their index (or even keep it). Simply pop the array with `.splice()` and provide the index with `$index` or `.indexOf()`. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.noOfTVs = [{
    index: 0, value: 'How many Dish TVs?'}, {
    index: 1, value: 'Connect 1 Dish TV'}, {
    index: 2, value: 'Connect 2 Dish TVs'}, {
    index: 3, value: 'Connect 3 Dish TVs'}, {
    index: 4, value: 'Connect 4 Dish TVs'}, {
    index: 5, value: 'Connect 5 Dish TVs'}, {
    index: 6, value: 'Connect 6 Dish TVs'}, {
    index: 7, value: 'Connect 7 Dish TVs'}, {
    index: 8, value: 'Connect 8 Dish TVs'}
  ];
  $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[0];

  $scope.onChangeMethod = function(index){ 
    /* can be like:
       $scope.noOfTVs[index].index = index;
    */
  }

  $scope.removetv = function(value) {
    var index = $scope.noOfTVs.indexOf(value);
    $scope.noOfTVs.splice(index, 1)
    $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[index - 1] || $scope.noOfTVs[index] || null;
  }

});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<h3>Demo App</h3>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="connectTVs" ng-change="onChangeMethod($index)" class="selector" aria-required="true" ng-options="noOfTV as noOfTV.value for noOfTV in noOfTVs">
      </select>
  <br><br>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="removetv(connectTVs)">Remove TV</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use splice here, because remove is happening from service and the no.of connect tv index should be based on the response. There is something wrong with the ng-options element

Comment: @UI_Dev you might want to edit your question to be slightly more specific about this part, I'm not sure what it supposed to look like and how it should work so that I can adjust my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are updating index after assigning ng-model in removetv() method.
And also, you updated index variable in this method.
Try this.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.noOfTVs = [{
    index: 0,
    value: 'How many Dish TVs?'
  }, {
    index: 1,
    value: 'Connect 1 Dish TV'
  }, {
    index: 2,
    value: 'Connect 2 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 3,
    value: 'Connect 3 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 4,
    value: 'Connect 4 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 5,
    value: 'Connect 5 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 6,
    value: 'Connect 6 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 7,
    value: 'Connect 7 Dish TVs'
  }, {
    index: 8,
    value: 'Connect 8 Dish TVs'
  }];
  $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[0];
  $scope.onChangeMethod = function(connectTVsIndex) {
    // Doing some actions
    $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[connectTVsIndex];
    alert($scope.connectTVs.index);
  }
  $scope.removetv = function(connectTVsIndex) {
    $scope.connectTVs.index = $scope.connectTVs.index - 1;
    alert($scope.connectTVs.index);
    $scope.connectTVs = $scope.noOfTVs[$scope.connectTVs.index];
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
<h3>Demo App</h3>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select id="connectTV" aria-label="How many Dish TVs" ng-model="connectTVs" ng-change="onChangeMethod(connectTVs.index)" class="selector" aria-required="true" ng-options="noOfTV as noOfTV.value for noOfTV in noOfTVs">
      </select>
<br><br>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="removetv(connectTVs.index)">Remove TV </button>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```